# Show that the polynomial has a root in the interval

Tags: polynomials

Show (only using polynomial properties, not using the Intermediate Value Theorem) that $p(x)=x^3+3x^2-2x-6$ has a root between 1 and 2.

Comment: The question is in the chapter of a book previous of limits and the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT...why not factorise it? $$p(x)=(x+3)(x^2-2)$$

Comment: you are right @David , thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 2):

You van simply plug into $p(x)$ the values $1$ and $2$: $p(1)=-4$ and $p(2)=10$, so there is a solution of $p(x)=0$ between $1$ and $2$.